# Showing Modulo Congruence Amongst Prime Divisors (Number Theory)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm having trouble figuring out how to show the general existence part of the following problem.

Suppose $n\in\{1,2,3...\}$ and $n\equiv 7\mod{10}$. Show that $\exists$ a prime divisor $p$ of $n$ s.t. $p\equiv 3\mod{10}$ or $p\equiv 7\mod{10}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Clearly in this case $p$ cannot be $2$ or $5$.  So the options are
$$p\equiv1,\,3,\,7,\,9\pmod{10}\ .$$
Now while $n$ may have prime factors congruent to $1$ or $9$, it cannot have **only** such factors, as then multiplying the prime factors together would give...

Can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Factor $n = ab$ then consider the values $a$ and $b$ may take mod 10.